# Fetching Data back from Modal in ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

As I mention `modal.onDidDismiss()` my button which opens modal stops working.

mypage.ts

```
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddToCartPage, {
      'merchant_id': this.merchantId,
      'item_id': list
    });
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      console.log('MODAL DATA', data);
    });
   modal.present();
```

I want to fetch this data from modal

my modal.ts codes

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss({
      Size: this.selectedSize,
      Spicy: this.selectedSpicy,
      TotalPrice: this.totalPrice()
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Can anyone help me in fixing this.

Comment: Where is the problem? your code looks fine. Is there any error on console or something else?

Comment: No i cant see console.log neither my button which usually opens modal isnt working after implementing modal.onDidDismiss().

Comment: And if you remove that lines, it works again? Maybe the problem is on the button

Comment: Found it. The problem was in the button. rewrote the code and now its working perfectly fine :) 
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**You can catch data in modal using `NavParams`**.

```
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';  

  merchentId: string;
  list: any[];

  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {

    this.merchentId = this.navParams.get('merchant_id');
    this.list = this.navParams.get('item_id');
  }
```

**[Find StackBlitz Example Here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-ionic-modal-example?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

Comment: My question is to get data back to parent page from modal.

Comment: OMG. any way what you did is correct. you can find it in my stackblitz example as well. go through it and let me know if there is any issue